# MAUI Android webview can not show local web page

Tags: maui

My app is downloading a web page mydownloadedpage.html.

The page is confirmed that stored and exists to the folder /data/user/0/com.xyx.qwerty/files/storage/mydownloadedpage.html

The webview on iOS works as supposed but at Android i'm getting ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Please note that the app has access to the file and there is no special code in the app.
I'm passing the above full path to webview source.

```
<WebView Source="/data/user/0/com.xyx.qwerty/files/storage/mydownloadedpage.html"/>
```

I have tried to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml with no luck.

The web view should show the local web page and work the same as in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to add `WebView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;` in Android.

Page.xaml:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <WebView x:Name="webview" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="500" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID        
            Android.Webkit.WebView web = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;        
            web.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;        
            web.LoadUrl("file:///data/data/com.companyname.mauiapp3/cache/Li.html");
#endif 
     
}
```

Format is `file://` + file path.